# How do I access resources in a console application?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

How do I gain access to `.Properties.Resources` in a console application?  This is to use resource files attached to the solution.

Here's exactly what I can see:
[image: everything about the program]

The first syntax error isn't the one I'm concerned with (*Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement*).

The one that I'm trying to fix is the second: *The name 'Properties' does not exist in the current context*

Comment: use test.Properties; then it will work;

Comment: `test.Properties` has exactly the same error.

Comment: @Joe.......... u haven't added the Resource file(as I have seen in your Solution Explorer). IN Order to add the Resource file right click on Project file and click on Properties and then Click on Resource from left pane. Click on create Default Resource file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edited answer** (after your edit):

You don't *have* resources.

Right-Click on 'test' in Solution Explorer -> Add -> New Item -> Resources File

Then double-click on the created file (e.g. Resource1.resx), and take it from there.

Then use it:

```
string s = Resource1.String1;
```

**Original answer**:

```
Text = Properties.Resources.String1;
```

For example.

EDIT:

Click on the little triangle next to `Properties` in `Solution Explorer`, then do the same for `Resources`. Then double click `Resources.Designer.cs`.

Then copy the namespace there like this:

```
TheNameSpace.Properties.Resources.String1;
```

Comment: Typing `Properties` gives me this error: The type or namespace name 'Properties' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Joe Is the namespace of the file you're typing in - the default one for that project?

Comment: @Joe Did you type a dot after the word Properties? - Don't just type **Properties** , type all of what I wrote in the answer.

Comment: In `Solution Explorer`, within `Properties`, there's only one file: `AssemblyInfo.cs`.  There is no folder called `Resources`.

Comment: It's usually a file named "Resources.resx". If you don't have one, then you don't have any resources.

Comment: @Joe OK. So you can't access any resource because it doesn't exist! What type of solution are you using? Windows Forms application? If so, it _should_ have one.

Comment: Take a look at the picture above, maybe that will explain more clearly what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Your application does not appear to *have* any resources.

Comment: The `example.txt` in the Solution Explorer -- is that a resource?  That's what I'm trying to access in code.

Comment: Why are you asking _me_ if that's a resource? It's _your_ project! Do you _want_ it to be a resource?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if I'm understanding C# terminology correctly.

Comment: It's a file. It would only have anything to do with resources if the "Build Action" in solution explorer was set to "Embedded resource".

Answer (score 0):

You need add your file as Resource, open project's Properties, select Resources tab. Then Press Add Resource > Add Existing file. Select your file.

Make sure added resource file has Build Action = Resource