# How do I create a Resources file for a Console Application?

Tags: c#, console-application, embedded-resource

I'm trying to use an embedded resource in a console application, but [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655520/how-do-i-access-properties-resources/16655668#comment23959341_16655668) console applications don't come with a resource file automatically.  How do I create a resources file for my console app?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The *project template* for a console mode application doesn't have pre-cooked Resources.  You simply add it with Project + Properties, Resources tab, click the "Click here to create one" link.  Take an hour and click around some more.  This is all very discoverable but you have to take a look.

Comment: "Take an Hour and click around some more"...  I see mushroom clouds in his future ;)

Comment: So do I :)  Incidentally, this did exactly what I needed, so thank you!

Comment: @Joe This is probably the best answer. I didn't know it could be done this way. And this way you get it in the customary place - inside `Properties`.

Answer (score 12):

Right click on the console application project node in the solution explorer. Add->New Item->Resources File.

edit: as has been pointed out, if you open the Properties of the console app project, it will also have a Resources tab, which will tell you that it doesn't have a resources file and provide you with a link to create one. This will do the same thing as the above, except that it will create the files under the Properties folder.

Answer (score 8):

I added the answer in my answer to your previous question:

Right-Click on 'test' in Solution Explorer -> Add -> New Item -> Resources File

Then double-click on the created file (e.g. Resource1.resx), and take it from there.

Then use it:

```
string s = Resource1.String1;
```

Comment: I did the same as mentioned above but also have to set the Access Modifier to "Public"

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click your project.
2. Select Properties.
3. In Resources click the link "This project does not contain a default resource file". Click here to add one.".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the fundamentals.

Just build your default

```
public class Lang {
    public string Title = "my title";
}
```

then

```
public class Lang_en_US : Lang{

    public Lang_en_US(){
        Title = "my US Title";
    }

}
```

then find your lang you want to case into with switch, if not match, just use the default

ASP.net compiles into classes like the global resource.

:)